# CSS - Можно ли анимировать clip на изображении, чтобы открывать квадранты по часовой стрелке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

У меня есть два круглых изображения. Верхнее изображение располагается абсолютно поверх нижнего изображения. Я показываю верхнее изображение с интервалом 25% с помощью клипа, и мне интересно, можно ли его анимировать, чтобы квадрант постепенно увеличивал угол, как часы.

В настоящее время у меня работает анимация, но она показывает только вертикальное направление, а не постепенное увеличение угла.

Я также открыт для других решений, не связанных с `clipPath`.

**Update:** Я также только что понял, что с помощью этого метода, который я использую, невозможно создать круг 3/4, хотя я полагаю, что мог бы просто добавить еще одно изображение с абсолютным положением и сделать одно из них 180 градусов по вертикали, а другое 180 градусов по горизонтали для этого.

```css
.image-container {
  position:relative;
  height:180px;
  width:180px;
  border-radius:180px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  .image-container img {
    max-width:100%;
  }
    .image-container img.top-image {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      clip: rect(0, 90px, 90px, 0);
      transform:rotate(90deg);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    .image-container:hover img.top-image {
      clip: rect(0, 180px, 90px, 0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png"/>
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [CSS - Possible to animate "clip" on an image to reveal quadrants clockwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68655274/7394871) от участника  [@user13286](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250782/user13286).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/a/68657520/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наложение на верхнюю картинку маски конического градиента - отличная идея, но анимировать его можно несколько по другому. Сами градиенты в `css` не поддаются анимации, но можно задать их отдельные свойства при помощи `css-переменных` и [анимировать уже их](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333786/11080686)

```css
@property --value {
  syntax: '<percentage>';
  initial-value: 50%;
  inherits: false;
}
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-container img.top-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  --value: 0%;
  -webkit-mask: conic-gradient(black var(--value), transparent 0);
  transition: --value 2s ease;
}

.image-container:nth-child(2) img.top-image{
  transition: --value 2s steps(4);
}

.image-container img.top-image:hover {
  --value: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>

<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

добавил второй варант анимирования по четвертям (изначально вроде про него спрашивали)

Comment: благодарю за отличный ответ и полезные ссылки

Comment: о, не знал, что можно css переменные не оборачивать в var

Comment: @МихаилКамахин а синтаксис var(--variable) используется только для получения значения переменной. В том же свойстве `transition` на месте `transition-property` используется не значение, а имя переменной(свойства). С непрозрачностью было бы например так `transition: opacity .3s ease`. Что интересно, ключевое слово `all` не включает в себя пользовательские свойства (переменные)

Comment: @zhurof а, понял

Comment: @МихаилКамахин плохо конечно, что в Firefox не работает. Но думаю через пол-годика подтянутся, как с `backdrop-filter` было

Answer (score 4):

clip-path может это сделать:

```css
.image-container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  display:grid;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  grid-area:1/1;
}
/* the 400% is an arbitrary big value*/
.image-container img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,400% 50%,50% 50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.image-container:hover img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,50% 400%,50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

Чтобы понять, что происходит, добавьте `box-shadow:`

```css
.image-container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  display:grid;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  grid-area:1/1;
}
/* the 400% is an arbitrary big value*/
.image-container img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,400% 50%,50% 50%);
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.image-container:hover img.top-image {
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,400% 0,400% 50%,50% 400%,50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68657421/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Спасибо за перевод!

Answer (score 4):

Если вам нужен «тикающий» эффект, такой как стрелка на аналоговых часах, вы можете использовать маску CSS с коническим градиентом, который постепенно откроет нижнее изображение.

Этот фрагмент создает анимацию CSS (используя JS, поскольку мне было лень вводить все это) с 60 точками анимации, каждый раз изменяя конический градиент на 6 градусов. Он добавляет анимацию к верхнему изображению при наведении курсора.

```js
// create the 60 part animation
let keyframes = '@keyframes tickround {';
for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
  keyframes += i * 100 / 60 + '% {-webkit-mask-image: conic-gradient(transparent ' + 6 * i + 'deg ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg, black ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg 360deg); mask-image: conic-gradient(transparent ' + 6 * i + 'deg ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg, black ' + 6 * (i + 1) + 'deg 360deg);}';
}
keyframes += '}';
const newstyle = document.createElement('style');
newstyle.innerHTML = keyframes;
document.head.appendChild(newstyle);
```

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-container img.top-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}

.image-container img.top-image:hover {
  animation: tickround 60s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68657520/7394871) от участника  [@A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с меньшими записями в таблице стилей. И без JavaScript.
Я решил анимировать CSS-переменные
Работает в основном в браузерах Chromium: https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-container img.top-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  --deg1: 0deg;
  --deg2: 0deg;
  --deg3: 0deg;
  --deg4: 360deg;
  -webkit-mask-image: conic-gradient(transparent var(--deg1) var(--deg2), black var(--deg3) var(--deg4));
  mask-image: conic-gradient(transparent var(--deg1) var(--deg2), black var(--deg3) var(--deg4));
}

.image-container:hover img.top-image {
  animation: tickround 60s steps(60) infinite;
}

@property --deg1 {
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
  syntax: '<angle>';
}

@property --deg2 {
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
  syntax: '<angle>';
}

@property --deg3 {
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
  syntax: '<angle>';
}

@property --deg4 {
  initial-value: 360deg;
  inherits: false;
  syntax: '<angle>';
}

@keyframes tickround {
  0% {
    --deg1: 0deg;
    --deg2: 6deg;
    --deg3: 6deg;
    --deg4: 360deg;
  }
  100% {
    --deg1: 360deg;
    --deg2: 366deg;
    --deg3: 366deg;
    --deg4: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="top-image" src="https://www.pngjoy.com/pngm/380/18164680_circle-frame-vector-brown-round-frame-clip-art.png" />
  <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/377/831/png-clipart-golden-circle-background-golden-circle-thumbnail.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, для меня тоже интересное решение.